# Magento Custom Options: How do I get and save them to the order?

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

I have a third party cashier that is not compatible yet with the custom options in Magento. In the cart all custom options are available and visible. But when I process the order with the cashier they are not saved and visible in the admin order view (or not saved at all).

However, if I use the standard cashier the custom options are saved.

So my question is how I can implement a support for the custom options in the new cashier.

**Question:** How do I retrieve the custom options together with their values (the customer enter them when adding the product) and then save them to the order (to make them visible in the admin order view)?

Note: I'm only using two text fields (e.g. customer can write two text messages when ordering the product).

The following is the code that push the saves the order:

```
    $order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')
    ->setIncrementId($reservedOrderId)
    ->setStoreId($storeId)
    ->setQuoteId(0)
    ->setGlobal_currency_code('SEK')
    ->setBase_currency_code('SEK')
    ->setStore_currency_code('SEK')
    ->setOrder_currency_code('SEK');

    if($customer == 0){
        // set Customer data
        $order->setCustomer_email($shipping['email'])
        ->setCustomerFirstname($shipping['given_name'])
        ->setCustomerLastname($shipping['family_name'])
        //->setCustomerGroupId($customer->getGroupId())
        //->setCustomer_is_guest(0)
        ->setCustomer($customer);
    }else{
        // set Customer data
        $order->setCustomer_email($customer->getEmail())
        ->setCustomerFirstname($customer->getFirstname())
        ->setCustomerLastname($customer->getLastname())
        ->setCustomerGroupId($customer->getGroupId())
        ->setCustomer_is_guest(0)
        ->setCustomer($customer);
    }

    // set Billing Address
    //$billing = $customer->getDefaultBillingAddress();
    $billingAddress = Mage::getModel('sales/order_address')
    ->setStoreId($storeId)
    ->setAddressType(Mage_Sales_Model_Quote_Address::TYPE_BILLING)
    //->setCustomerId($customer->getId())
    //->setCustomerAddressId($customer->getDefaultBilling())
    //->setCustomer_address_id($billing->getEntityId())
    //->setPrefix($billing->getPrefix())
    ->setFirstname($billing['given_name'])
    //->setMiddlename($billing->getMiddlename())
    ->setLastname($billing['family_name'])
    //->setSuffix($billing->getSuffix())
    //->setCompany($shipping->getCompanyName())
    ->setStreet($billing['street_address'])
    ->setCity($billing['city'])
    ->setCountry_id($billing['country'])
    //->setRegion($billing->getRegion())
    //->setRegion_id($billing->getRegionId())
    ->setPostcode($billing['postal_code'])
    ->setTelephone($billing['phone']);
    //->setFax($billing->getFax());

    $order->setBillingAddress($billingAddress);

    //$shipping = $customer->getDefaultShippingAddress();
    $shippingAddress = Mage::getModel('sales/order_address')
    ->setStoreId($storeId)
    ->setAddressType(Mage_Sales_Model_Quote_Address::TYPE_SHIPPING)
    //->setCustomerId($customer->getId())
    //->setCustomerAddressId($customer->getDefaultBilling())
    //->setCustomer_address_id($shipping->getEntityId())
    //->setPrefix($shipping->getPrefix())
    ->setFirstname($shipping['given_name'])
    //->setMiddlename($shipping->getMiddlename())
    ->setLastname($shipping['family_name'])
    //->setSuffix($shipping->getSuffix())
    //->setCompany($shipping->getCompanyName())
    ->setStreet($shipping['street_address'])
    ->setCity($shipping['city'])
    ->setCountry_id($shipping['country'])
    //->setRegion($shipping->getRegion())
    //->setRegion_id($shipping->getRegionId())
    ->setPostcode($shipping['postal_code'])
    ->setTelephone($shipping['phone']);
    //->setFax($shipping->getFax());

    $itemcount = count($cart);
    $cartItem = $cart[$itemcount-1];
    if($cartItem['reference'] == 'SHIPPING'){
        if($cartItem['unit_price'] == 0){
            $order->setShippingAddress($shippingAddress)
            ->setShipping_method('freeshipping_freeshipping')
            ->setShippingAmount(0)
            ->setShippingDescription('Standardfrakt - Sverige');
        }else{
            $order->setShippingAddress($shippingAddress)
            ->setShipping_method('flatrate_flatrate')
            ->setShippingAmount($ship)
            ->setShippingDescription('Standardfrakt - Sverige');
        }
    }

    // $order->setShippingAddress($shippingAddress)
    // ->setShippingMethod('apport_2') // där X är id i databasen på fraktsättet
    // ->setShippingDescription("DB Schenker"); // Kan läggas in ett eget namn på fraktsättet om ni vill

    $orderPayment = Mage::getModel('sales/order_payment')
    ->setStoreId($storeId)
    ->setCustomerPaymentId(0)
    ->setMethod('purchaseorder')
    ->setPo_number($reservation);
    $order->setPayment($orderPayment);

    $allitems = array();
    $itemcount = count($cart);
    for($i = 0; $i < ($itemcount - 1); $i++){
        $cartItem = $cart[$i];
        if($cartItem['type'] == 'discount'){
            $discount = $cartItem['unit_price'] / 100;
            $discount = abs($discount);
        }else{
            $number += $cartItem['quantity'];
        }
    }

    $discount = $discount / $number;

    for($i = 0; $i < ($itemcount - 1); $i++){
        $cartItem = $cart[$i];
        if($cartItem['reference'] == 'PROMO'){
        }else{
            $product_name = $cartItem['reference'];
            $discounttotal = $discount * $cartItem['quantity'];
            //$discount = ($cartItem['unit_price'] / 100) - ($cartItem['total_price_including_tax'] / 100);
            $taxrate = ($cartItem['tax_rate'] / 100);
            $taxamount = ($cartItem['total_price_including_tax'] / 100) - ($cartItem['total_price_excluding_tax'] / 100);
            $price = ($cartItem['total_price_including_tax'] / 100);
            $model = Mage::getModel('catalog/product'); //getting product model
            $collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()->addStoreFilter(); //products collection
            $nr = (int)$cartItem['quantity'];
            $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->loadByAttribute('sku',$product_name);
        //     foreach ($collection as $product) {
        //         $model->load($product->getId());
        //         $pname = $model->getSku();
        //         if(strcmp($pname,$product_name)==0) {
                    $id = $product->getId();
                    $stock = Mage::getModel('cataloginventory/stock_item')->loadByProduct($id);
                    $stock->setQty((int)$stock->getQty() - $nr);
                    $stock->save();
        //         }
        //     }
            $allitems[$id] = array('qty' => $nr,
                                    'discount' => $discounttotal,
                                    'taxrate' => $taxrate,
                                    'price' => $price,
                                    'taxamount' => $taxamount);
        }
    }
    $subTotal = 0;
    $exTotal = 0;
    $products = $allitems;

    // Mage::log(print_r($products, 1), null, 'mynewlog.log');


    foreach ($products as $productId=>$product) {
    $_product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($productId);
    $rawtotal = ($_product->getFinalPrice() - ($product['taxamount'] / $product['qty'])) * $product['qty'];
    $rowTotal = $product['price'];          


    $orderItem = Mage::getModel('sales/order_item')
    ->setStoreId($storeId)
    ->setQuoteItemId(0)
    ->setQuoteParentItemId(NULL)
    ->setProductId($productId)
    ->setProductType($_product->getTypeId())
    ->setQtyBackordered(NULL)
    ->setTotalQtyOrdered($product['qty'])
    ->setQtyOrdered($product['qty'])
    ->setName($_product->getName())
    ->setSku($_product->getSku())
    ->setWeight($_product->getWeight())
    ->setPrice($_product->getFinalPrice())
    ->setBasePrice($product['price'])
    ->setOriginalPrice($_product->getPrice())
    ->setTaxPercent($product['taxrate'])
    ->setTaxAmount($product['taxamount'])
    ->setDiscountAmount($product['discount'])
    ->setRowTotal($rawtotal)
    ->setBaseRowTotal($rowTotal);   


    $stotal = $product['price'] - $product['discount'];
    $etotal = $product['price'] - $product['taxamount'] - $product['discount'];
    $disco += $product['discount'];
    $taxam += $product['taxamount'];
    $subTotal += $stotal;
    $exTotal += $etotal;
    $order->addItem($orderItem);
    }

    $taxam += ($ship / 5);
    $order->setSubtotal($exTotal)
    ->setCoupon_code($couponcode)
    ->setDiscountDescription($couponcode)
    ->setStoreId($store)
    ->setDiscountAmount($disco)
    ->setTaxAmount($taxam)
    ->setSubtotal_incl_tax($subTotal)
    ->setBaseToGlobalRate(1)
    ->setBaseSubtotal($subTotal)
    ->setGrandTotal($subTotal + $ship)
    ->setBaseGrandTotal($subTotal + $ship);

    $transaction->addObject($order);
    $transaction->addCommitCallback(array($order, 'place'));
    $transaction->addCommitCallback(array($order, 'save'));
    $transaction->save();

        // At this point make sure the order is created in your system and send a
        // confirmation email to the customer
        $order->load(Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getLastOrderId());
        $order->sendNewOrderEmail();
        $order->setEmailSent(true);
        $order->save();
```

Answer (score 0):

Magento,please modify code

```
->setGlobal_currency_code('SEK')
    ->setBase_currency_code('SEK')
    ->setStore_currency_code('SEK')
    ->setOrder_currency_code('SEK');
```

used below

```
 ->setGlobalCurrencyCode('SEK')
        ->setBaseCurrencyCode('SEK')
        ->setStoreCurrencyCode('SEK')
```

Please follow link http://inchoo.net/ecommerce/magento/programmatically-create-order-in-magento/